# Peer review maatkits mk-parallel-dump and mk-parallel-restore usage?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to make use of maatkit as a means of dumping a database and then restoring to another database.

For dumps:
mk-parallel-dump --user abc --password xyz --databases $db --base-dir /tmp/dump

For restore:
mk-parallel-restore --create-databases --user abc --password xyz --database devdb /tmp/dump

My question is, is my logic and understanding correct, and would it be ok to do it like this.

Kind Regards
Brent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work as expected.  However, do some benchmarks on the time using Mysqldump and Maakit's parallel dump.  It is not always faster in our experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `ionice -c1 -n7` in order to rise the run level of the command to do.

You can also tell how many tread you want to allocate to your command, like dumping or restoring 3 tables at the same time.

[More stuff here](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-restore.html)